# nodejs IoT device to device communication

Tags: node.js, iot, communication-protocol

so im working on a my bachelor thesis and for that i need to implement, in a smarthome, d2d communication between IoT devices. So i want to implement the usuall server work, like noticing if a device connects/ disconnects etc. to the IoT devices, so no server/hub is needed at home. 
But I can't find good solutions for it, for websockets i need a server, for mqtt a broker and so on, but all need a server.
I found that d2d is done with "LTE" similar technology but i would like to do it with web-protocols.

So my question:
Is there a way to let IoT devices talk to each other over the network?

My IoT devices (raspberry pis) currently use nodejs  with typescript but I'm  not starting a server, they only have a mqtt connection to publish there sensor data to the users.

Thanks in advance.
And if im understanding something wrong, please say it. :)

Comment: Just to make things clear: you want to realize an ad-hoc network with your devices, right?

Comment: How will the data go from the devices to the user? How will it be stored long-term? It is easy enough to communicate peer2peer between the devices, but usually the two questions lead to needing a server somewhere anyway...

Comment: You can say it like that... My goal is just that the devices talk to each other without a server between them.  And I would like to use some sort of web-protocol if possible or useful.

Comment: @jonnor I have a Serverless rest api on aws and lambda functions that talk to the client and the iot devices.  But for the most time the iot devices get messages from the user through mqtt.

Comment: Where is located the mqtt broker? You affirmed that devices have an mqtt connection. If you have access to this broker, I can suggest something that you can use.

Comment: @DaltonCézane for clarification. One Raspi hase a Ledstrip connected to it and i want to controll it, thats why it has an mqtt connection, just for receiving a new value for the led and sending real time data to the user. I currently use a public Mqtt broker but i will switch to an amazon broker soon.

Comment: Is it a requirement that devices have to communicate directly between them? Or, for example, can one device send a message to a "dispatcher" and this one be responsible to deliver the message for the end device?

Comment: @DaltonCézane I want to analyze im my bachelor thesis if it isn't better to let the devices talk to each other instead of having a hub/server or similar taht the iot devices talk to

Comment: In this case, you have to worry about the topology of devices, network infrastructure, mobility, number of devices, etc. You will have many factors. You can run experiments with an ad hoc and a mesh network. You have to define well what you will be investigating and what will be your "research" questions...

Comment: @DaltonCézane Thank you , now i have an idea what to look for and try some things out :)